# Can we combine regular for loops with for in

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am curious but Google is not helping on this one...

We are looking for a tidy way of using an object key (it is an object containing functions) while also having clean access to the key names.

```
var obj={'key1':'val1','key2':'val2','key3':'val3'};
```

To get the desired key names in a loop we do: **EDIT: this is wrong!**

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
    console.log(Object.keys(obj)[i]);
    }
```

but would it be possible in this kind of loop?

```
for(var k in obj){
    //?
    }
```

I have seen combination loops before using &&. Is JavaScript able to do an elegant  combination of both?

The closest I have got without disrupting the standard loop is:

```
var i=0;
for(var k in obj){
    console.log(Object.keys(obj)[i]);
    i++;
    }
```

but it is hardly elegant, not very innovative, it is more of a work around because 'i' is declared outside of the loop. Everything else we have tried errors.

Comment: Your first loop isn't even valid. `obj.length` is undefined because `obj`, as you've defined it, is a object and not an array.

Comment: thanks, I think my brain is frazzled

Comment: @8DK This happens. Don't worry, just go on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question, it's the simplest ever thing.

```
for(var k in obj){
    console.log(k);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? Wasn't it what's asked ?

Comment: (I don't mean it should be upvoted either...)

Comment: Well it is a perfectly good answer.

Comment: I know! some people are haters on here! Lol i must be REALLY tired. that is soooo easy its shocking! +1

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { console.log(key); });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the keys:

```
for(var k in obj) {
  console.log(k)
}
```

If you need the values:

```
for(var k in obj) {
  console.log(obj[k])
}
```

Comment: +1, I like the style of your answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print out the keys and values?

```
for(var k in obj){
    console.log(k,obj[k]);
}
```